# Argument 'myCtrl' is not a function, got undefined is persistant

Tags: angularjs

There are many answers out there but not quite to the point, so I'd like to ask again. I'm trying to use a peace of Angular code I found:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <body>
    <h3>Select some text </h3>
    <div ng-mouseup="showSelectedText()">
        Do you think that facebook, twitter, linkedin are designed to make people addict ?, Then you have to read this article. The most popular social networking sites are following people's habit. It is not concept, it is people's habit
    </div>
    <br/>
    <h3>Selected Text</h3>
    <div ng-bind="selectedText"></div>
    <script>
        function myCtrl($scope) {

            $scope.showSelectedText = function() {
                $scope.selectedText =  $scope.getSelectionText();
            };

            $scope.getSelectionText = function() {
              var text = "";
              if (window.getSelection) {
                  text = window.getSelection().toString();
              } else if (window.getSelection && window.getSelection.type != "Control") {
                  text = document.selection.createRange().text;
              }
              return text;
            };
        }
    </script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And for some reason it keeps returning me an error:

```
Argument 'myCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

When trying to change to `ng-app="myApp"` I'm getting this error:

```
Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error
```

I understand that with the new angular version there's some migration to be made around the syntax of using the ng-controller, but I can't quite figure out what I'm supposed to do.

Thank you in advance!
Amir

Comment: [works fine here](http://plnkr.co/edit/s8SwnY8og1xR8Yt8OKbN?p=preview) with your exact code. Note however global functions are not supported as controllers directly after version 1.3

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your html `ng-app="myApp"` and this should be your script.

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);
function myCtrl($scope) {

$scope.showSelectedText = function() {
    $scope.selectedText =  $scope.getSelectionText();
};

$scope.getSelectionText = function() {
  var text = "";
  if (window.getSelection) {
      text = window.getSelection().toString();
  } else if (window.getSelection && window.getSelection.type != "Control") {
      text = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  return text;
};
}
</script>
```

Load the angular.min.js upfront, before ur custom script

Working plunker :  http://plnkr.co/edit/2Vb8nCYVhI9vMdHvn3Yf?p=preview